# How to make a TextBox accept only alphabetic characters?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can I make a `TextBox` only accept alphabetic characters with spaces?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the following snippet:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
        textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work pretty well. If I add a letter and then a number / whitespace / whatever it will let me go as I am satisfying the regex (start with letter).

Comment: @favoretti now code works fine, but there's an exception occurs if I type the first character integer and when i press the backspace key to remove that. Code works fine for numeric, it pops the message when I type the numeric. but when I tried to clear with backspace it gives me the error StartIndex cannot be less than zero, parameter name startIndex. How to handle this?

Answer (score 19):

You can try by handling the `KeyPress` event for the textbox

```
void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
}
```

Additionally say allow backspace in case you want to remove some text, this should work perfectly fine for you

**EDIT**

The above code won't work for paste in the field for which i believe you will have to use `TextChanged` event but then it would be a bit more complicated with you having to remove the incorrect char or highlight it and place the cursor for the user to make the correction Or maybe you could validate once the user has entered the complete text and tabs off the control.

Comment: This one works great but it won't allow me to paste a text that should be passing the validation.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void textbox1_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z)
    {
    }
    else
    {
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to handle the TextChangedEvent and check what's been typed:

```
string oldText = string.Empty;
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.All(chr => char.IsLetter(chr)))
        {
            oldText = textBox2.Text;
            textBox2.Text = oldText;

            textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            textBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = oldText;
            textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            textBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
    }
```

This is a regex-free version if you prefer. It will make the text box blink on bad input.
Please note that it also seems to support paste operations as well.

Comment: sir that was great but can you tell me in deatail how the typing is stopped automaticallu it is only the if loop which checks but how the typing is stopped?
 and about lambda expression? textBox1.Text.All(chr => char.IsLetter(chr)) what is this all about. means how this works please if you can

Comment: Hey! Well what it does it so store the previous text from the input in teh oldText variable. Then on subsequent change of the textbox it checks character by character and if the character is not a letter - it returns the old text. If it is - it sets the old text to be the same as the current (new) textbox input.
So if you have a valid input - the oldText get's the TextBox value, if you have invalid output - it works the other way around. Also some GUi styling helps visualize if there is an error or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: So the textBox2.Text.All() lambda will return false if even one character is not a letter. If all are letters - it will return true. From then on the above explanation takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Write Code in Text_KeyPress Event as

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is working absolutely fine...

```
 private void manufacturerOrSupplierTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            return;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for IsControl check.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses regular expressions, does not allow invalid characters to be pasted into the text box and maintains the cursor position.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

int CursorWas;
string WhatItWas;

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WhatItWas = textBox1.Text;
    }

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]*$"))
        {
            WhatItWas = textBox1.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            CursorWas = textBox1.SelectionStart == 0 ? 0 : textBox1.SelectionStart - 1;
            textBox1.Text = WhatItWas;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = CursorWas;
        }
    }
```

Note: textBox1_TextChanged recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

```
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        { 
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            MessageBox.Show("Enter only Alphabets");


        }
```

Please Try this

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9')
                e.Handled = true;
            else
                e.Handled = false;
        }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of why your answer will work and how to hook up the text box to your event.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
            private void tbCustomerName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back||e.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Space);
    }
```

It Allows White Spaces Too

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code that alert at the time of key press event

```
private void tbOwnerName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        //===================to accept only charactrs & space/backspace=============================================

        if (e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            MessageBox.Show("enter characters only");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution and it works as planned:

```
string errmsg = "ERROR : Wrong input";
ErrorLbl.Text = errmsg;

if (e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))
{
  ErrorLbl.Text = "ERROR : Wrong input";
}
else ErrorLbl.Text = string.Empty;
if (ErrorLbl.Text == errmsg)
{
  Nametxt.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) &&
         (e.KeyChar !='.'))
        { 
          e.Handled = true;
          MessageBox.Show("Only Alphabets");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain better your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in KeyPress event of textbox

```
if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) == false  & 
        Convert.ToString(e.KeyChar) != Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbBack)
            e.Handled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as far as characters restriction, Any suggestions on error msg prompt with my code if it's not C OR L

```
Private Sub TXTBOX_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TXTBOX.TextChanged

        Dim allowed As String = "C,L"
        For Each C As Char In TXTBOX.Text
            If allowed.Contains(C) = False Then

                TXTBOX.Text = TXTBOX.Text.Remove(TXTBOX.SelectionStart - 1, 1)
                TXTBOX.Select(TXTBOX.Text.Count, 0)

            End If

        Next
      
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me, even though not the simplest one.

```
private void Alpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char letter in inputTXT.Text)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(letter))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            if (count != inputTXT.Text.Length)
            {
                errorBox.Text = "The input text must contain only alphabetic characters";
            }
            else
            {
                errorBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Spaces and shortcut keys work

```
 if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```