# Only Allow to enter Numeric values Datagridview specific column

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there any way to customize datagridview  column to accept only numeric values. Also if user press any other character other than numbers nothing must type on the current cell.Is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: regular expression can be your close friend...

Comment: Look for "javascript filter input", for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Comment: I divide your question in two parts for simplicity:
1-  Is there any way to customize datagridview column to accept only numeric values: I think it totally depends on your gridview datasource . May be there is some way but need to google this.

2- if user press any other character other than numbers nothing must type on the current cell : Yes ofcorse we can use JavaScript function to allow the user to enter only numeric values.

Comment: I guess this is winform so you could try handling the keypress event for the editing control of that particular column [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321871/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-alphabets/8321942#8321942)

Comment: @V4Vendetta I think you gave me a nice clue I will follow it and see what happen

Comment: Use a regular expression. Or if its being enterd into a database set the database type to INT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use datagridview Editingcontrolshowing .. Basicly like this

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)    
{
String sCellName =  dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name; 
    If (UCase(sCellName) == "QUANTITY") //----change with yours
    {

        e.Control.KeyPress  += new KeyPressEventHandler(CheckKey);

     }
}

private void CheckKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }   
}
```

You can improve this CheckKey ...

Comment: not work error in calling event fix that e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(CheckKey);

Comment: I know it's a few years late, but it's always good practice to unhook your event handler so you don't end up with tons of subscribers, e.g e.Control.KeyPress -= CheckKey before subscribing.

Answer (score 9):

```
    private void gvAppSummary_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvAppSummary.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == intRate)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(gvAppSummary_KeyPress);
        }
    }

    private void gvAppSummary_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: 'intRate' is the ColumnIndex of the column that should only accept numeric values. Therefore this solution is a bit more beautiful than matzone's

Answer (score 4):

With the previous solutions, every time you enter the EditingControlShowing event, you will add the KeyPressEvent in «the list» of events to perform on KeyPress. This can easily be checked by setting a breakpoint in the KeyPress event.

Better solution would be:

```
private static KeyPressEventHandler NumericCheckHandler = new KeyPressEventHandler(NumericCheck);
private void dataGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == numericColumn.Index)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= NumericCheckHandler;
        e.Control.KeyPress += NumericCheckHandler;
    }
}
```

And the Event NumericCheck:

```
private static void NumericCheck(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl s = sender as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    if (s != null && (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ','))
    {
        e.KeyChar = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
        e.Handled = s.Text.Contains(e.KeyChar);
    }
    else
        e.Handled = !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column18qty_KeyPress);
                if (dgvProduct.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 18) //dgvtxtQty
                {
                    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                    if (tb != null)
                    {
                        tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column18qty_KeyPress);
                    }
                }
 private void Column18qty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
            && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            // only allow one decimal point
            if (e.KeyChar == '.'
                && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```