# In C# dot net windows application, textBox allow only alphabets. Not allow integers

Tags: c#

Here I want to validate that box only having alphabets which is starting with capital and continues with simple letters.

I have no idea about it. Help!

Comment: Also in `TextChanged` event, you can check first character is `Uppercase` and the other characters are `Lowercase` or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a website for asking specific programming questions. You also need to show your research effort! Additionally, please note that we are not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Directly you can not make it happen rather than use regex here.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]")
```

This will provide you Boolean result and accordance with it you can modify accordinly.

This link will help you

[Validate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321871/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-alphabetic-characters)

Thanks

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Comment: Please don't give a link-only answer. Explain it a bit more!