# Try catch not showing error message for formatException

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to catch `FormatException` from a text box. For example - if user enters number or any other character inside name text box field. Message will pop up - something went wrong. I'm fairly new to C# and I don't understand the concept of exceptions. Below does not work. What is correct exception for invalid format?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    int age = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

}
catch (FormatException )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: What value you are entering in `textBox1` and `textBox2` ?

Comment: What message you want to see in MessageBox?

Comment: Try catch is invoked on button click. I am entering name in text box1 which is must be in string format otherwise I want to show message box saying "Something went wrong".

Comment: You are not doing any validation around `textBox1.Text`. That's why you are not getting the error. If you want user to enter only string value (NOT the number) you can implement it multiple ways. Check [This Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321871/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-alphabetic-characters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a TextBox accept only alphabetic characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321871/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-alphabetic-characters)

Comment: @harpreet - Can you please confirm your requirement? Your code would only throw an exception if the `textBox2.Text` contained a non-number, but you've said you want the exception if it contains a number. What if it contained part of a number? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Please clarify with examples.  Describe what you entered into *both* text boxes.  And tell us both your *expected* results and *actual* results.  I ask for this because it's unclear what you want to have happen.  If I had to guess, at this point, it seems like you want to forbid someone from entering a number into the "name" textbox.  Is that right?  Did you know that int.Parse will throw an exception if you pass it an empty string?  Likely your textBox2 is just empty when you click the button and that's why the exception happens - because textBox2.Text is empty.

Comment: I expect the textbox1 to accept only string value i.e. any name. If user enters any other characters or number and click the button, I want to show error message showing- "Something went wrong". Similar is case for textbox2- which accepts age (must be a positive integer). If I enter age in any other than required format - and click the button- again I want the message saying - "Something went wrong". I also want to catch NullReferenceException. I hope this clear things up.

Comment: An example- I entered something like -"&123" in textbox1 and click the submit button. The message will pop up  showing -"Something went wrong" (Any random message). Similarly, If I enter "abc" in texbox2 - try catch must handle the format exception and  show error in message box. This is what I want so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to show the message.

```html
    try
        {
            double mydoubleParam = 0;
            // Assuming textBox1.Text is Name test box
            if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out mydoubleParam))
            {
                 new Exception(" Numeric value in name field");
            }

            int age = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);// Assuming Number text box

            MessageBox.Show("How are you today?");
        }

        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
        }
```

Comment: what if textBox1 has value "Am123t" .. is it valid ? if no, your code is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it in the TextChanged event like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
            if (isNumeric)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Even If i doubt to call it perfect, This answer makes sense +1 - just add code to avoid all other non-alphabetic characters and also make sure they are not append in the string of textBox's text after this validation.

Answer (score -1):

```
 catch (FormatException  ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong " + ex.ToString() );
    }
```

USE ex as variable in Catch.

UPDATE (As per comment )

```
 catch (FormatException  ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong !");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show only message inside double quotes?

Comment: Requirement : " For example - if user enters number inside name text box field. Message will pop up - something went wrong. "

Comment: What has passing `ex` into the handler got to do with the question?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to check for numbers inside the name textbox, then:

```
try {
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]");
        if (regex.IsMatch(name)) {
            throws new FormatException();
        }
        int age = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("How are you today?");
    }
    catch (FormatException) {
       MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
    }
```

You should also show a more specific message for each of the cases.

**UPDATE**

What you should really be doing is:

```
var regex = new Regex("[0-9]");
if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("There was a number inside name textbox.","Error in name field!");
    return;
}
try {
    Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
} catch (Exception) {
    MessageBox.Show("The input in age field was not valid","Error in name field!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Requirement : " For example - if user enters number inside name text box field. Message will pop up - something went wrong. "

Comment: @Amit - I suspect that the OP mistyped the requirement. I'm fairly certain he meant the opposite.

Comment: Your regex is broken and there's little point throwing the `FormatException` because that's what `int.Parse` will do anyway. You've posted incorrect code that just adds bloat.

Comment: @Enigmativity in comment section too he confirmed it."Try catch is invoked on button click. I am entering name in text box1 which is must be in string format otherwise I want to show message box saying "Something went wrong" .. however I didn't downvote this answer, instead I want it to be modified for correct requirement.

Comment: @Amit - I've asked the OP to confirm.

Comment: the textbox1 should be a name (Vinícius, Amit, or Enigmativity are valid), but Vini2010 or Am1t are not. To make a full validation of the string being a name is hard. I simply helped him with the part "if the user enters a number inside name text box field. Message will pop up - something went wrong".

Comment: textbox2 is age so is must be a number. If the user enters "two", the code  will automatically throw a exception in the line: "int age = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);".

Comment: There are very few occasions where `catch (Exception)` is the right thing to do.